# How do I allow background elements to poke out past the content area of an HTML page?

Tags: html, css

I want to create an HTML/CSS layout for a page where there are multiple images that poke outside the content area of the page.  The layout for the content area is fixed width and centered.  I do not want scrollbars to appear if the user's window is as narrow as the content area.

The content area is a container div with a fixed width and `margin: auto 0;`

Ideas I've considered:

1. Use CSS 3 Multiple Backgrounds on the `<body>` tag.  The background elements would have to be relative to the body, and wouldn't center with the content area.
2. Use negative margin or relatively positioned divs.  This would make scrollbars appear if people had their browser width smaller than the width of the images that poke out past the content area.

I want the images to be kind of bonus content for people who have their browser windows fullscreen but not seem necessary.

[image]

Here's some example HTML/CSS that would simulate this example.

css:

```
#containerDiv { 
    width: 910px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

html:

```
<html>
<head>[...]</head>
<body>
    <div id="containerDiv">
        <header>HEADER</header>
        <section id="contentArea">
            <h1>Content</h1>
        </section>
        <footer>FOOTER</footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your markup look like, if you have any already? That'll help immensely in figuring out a solution.

Comment: I'll add a simple example, thanks, but I'm willing to use any HTML/CSS combination that would get my needs met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrollbar problem of your second idea could be simply fixed by setting:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

The images would appear as much as they can according to the window size of the client; thus they would look like background, and only appear to those who have a higher screen resolution, without cluttering the lower-resolution people's screens.

Edit:

To get the images as you put in the example, use `position: absolute` and set their `left`s, `right`s and `top`s as you see need. You could use a script to check whether the page hit a certain height; and when so, add the next picture you set.

Comment: Does this work for relatively positioned elements pushed outside the content area?

Comment: Yes. At least in Webkit browsers and Firefox, and I'm mostly sure IE and older Opera too.